# What Perl module turns a file extension (.txt, .jpeg) into a mime type (text/plain, image/jpeg)?

Tags: perl, module, mime-types

What Perl module turns a file extension (.txt, .jpeg) into a mime type (text/plain, image/jpeg)?

I want

```
my $mime = file_to_mime ("some.txt");
# $mime = 'text/plain'
```

Comment: Try https://metacpan.org/pod/File::MimeInfo

Answer (score 5):

Although the answer by davewood is correct, it does a lot of checks and making things very explicit. [`MIME::Types`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Types) does the right thing out of the box!

There is no need to split the filename to extract the file extension. If you provide a filename with extension, it will extract it by itself.
If the text does not have an extension, then it will use that string as the extension.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Types; # by Mark Overmeer

my $filename = "some.txt";

my $MIME_Types = MIME::Types->new;

my $mimetype = $MIME_Types->mimeTypeOf($filename)
    or die "Could not find MIME type for '$filename'";

print "Filename '$filename' of MIME type '$mimetype'\n";
```

NOTE: **Never rely on the extension only**, you might consider [`File::Type`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Type) that introspects the file itself, or a more recent module [`File::MimeInfo::Magic`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::MimeInfo::Magic).

Comment: I marked this answer as correct, but then found out MIME::Types is "not great". File::Type has some amazing reviews on cpanratings. Also I do not need the magic. Sorry but I had to remove the accepted status.

Comment: @ChewyDragees you are free to mark answers as correct or not, but the answer provided was correct exactly what you asked for. You requested an answer to convert a $filename string into a $mimetype string. I only hinted that: just relying on the extension itself can be tricky and that file-introspection using Magic is much safer (and more expansive). File::Type having great reviews is because it is so versatile. Meaning "not great" is simply because it does the thing done quickly and easy and is providing more info about the MIME-type like the encoding or if it's binary or not. Just different.

Comment: you seem angry for some reason.

Comment: Me and being angry - that takes a whole lot more - and I probably would not respond at all in such mood :-D - but having given 'the right answer' and then pulled away losing 15 credits :-( --- never mind, enjoy the nice sunday-afternoon

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: The answer by Th.J. is probably better. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22832209/1702521) but I'll leave mine unedited for completeness sake.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/ say /;
use MIME::Types;

my $file = "foo.txt";

my $mime_types = MIME::Types->new( only_complete => 1 );
$mime_types->create_type_index;

my ($ext) = $file =~ /\.(.+?)$/;

die "Could not find file extension. (" . $file . ")"
  unless defined $ext;

my $content_type = $mime_types->mimeTypeOf($ext);

die "No content-type found for '$ext'"
  unless defined $content_type;


say $content_type;
```

- [MIME::Types](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Types)